# Show that $L^{\infty}$ space does not have a countable dense set.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I was able to show that when $p ≥ 1$, the $L^p$ space on the interval $[0,1]$ has a countable dense set.

However, when $p$ is infinite, how to prove that $L^p$ space on the interval $[0,1]$ does not have a countable dense set? I can't find some way to approach.

Comment: Try to find an uncountable subset such that the minimal distance between two elements is non-zero.

Comment: For example: $\{1,0\}^{\Bbb N}$ is such a subset of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: A roundabout, but interesting, way would be the following. Suppose $L^\infty$ is separable. Then the closed unit ball in $L^1$ is weak-* compact. Now present a counterexample to this (a sequence in the closed unit ball of $L^1$ with no weakly convergent subsequence). The classic example of such a sequence is $n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_s(x) = \chi_{[0,s]}(x)$. If $0 \le s < t \le 1$, what is $\|f_s - f_t\|_\infty$?

Answer (score -1):

Consider all those elements $e_i$ whose terms are either $0$ or $1$ .They all belong to $L^\infty$ and they are uncountable having cardinality $c$

$||e_i-e_j||=1$

Now if we a countable dense set $D$ say then we should have for each $e_i$ an element $d_i$ such that $||e_i-d_i||<\epsilon $ for any $\epsilon $>0(take $\epsilon=\dfrac{1}{2}$)

This is not possible as $D$ is countable

Comment: You have presented an answer for $\ell^\infty$, that is, $L^\infty(\mathbb{N},c)$, where $c$ is the counting measure. The OP is asking about the case $L^\infty([0,1],m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Of course using something like binary expansion you can translate between the two, but still, this is not an answer to the question as it was asked.